# Get a count of individual instances of a value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two fields, `inbound` and `outbound`, both of which are text values. I want to get all a count of all instances of a specific value in either or both of those columns.

Here's an example of the schema with some values and my query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE widgets (
  id int(5) auto_increment,
  inbound varchar(200),
  outbound varchar(200),
  event_name varchar(255),
  start_time int(11),
  primary key(id)
  );

  INSERT INTO widgets values (NULL, 'my_widget', 'other_widget', 'STARTED', unix_timestamp());
  INSERT INTO widgets values (NULL, 'my_widget', 'my_widget', 'STARTED', unix_timestamp());
  INSERT INTO widgets values (NULL, 'my_widget', 'my_widget', 'STARTED', unix_timestamp());

SELECT count(*)
            FROM (
                SELECT inbound, outbound, event_name
                FROM `widgets`
                ORDER BY `start_time` DESC
                LIMIT 10000
            ) AS t
            WHERE
              (t.`inbound` = 'my_widget'
                OR
                t.`outbound` = 'my_widget'
              )
            AND event_name != 'FINISHED'
```

[Here's an SQL fiddle with the schema and my current query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4261b/2/0)

Currently I'm getting a `count` of 3 appearances of `my_widget`, however I want to count all 5 appearances of `my_widget`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Incidentally, the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost meaningless, and probably best ignored.

Comment: And you only have 3 widgets !?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with `case` statement, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9czbiuh8M1c7w5qnYNWxo/1).

```
select
  sum(total) as total
from
(
  select
    sum(case when inbound = 'my_widget' then 1 else 0 end) as total
  from widgets
  where event_name <> 'FINISHED'
  union all
  select
    sum(case when outbound = 'my_widget' then 1 else 0 end) as total
  from widgets
  where event_name <> 'FINISHED'
) t
```

Output:

```
*-------* 
| total |
*-------*
|    5  |
*-------*
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks @zealous! It outputs exactly what I want, and as a bonus it's significantly faster and less complex than my previous version!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of *rows*, then use:

```
select count(*) as total
from widgets
where event_name <> 'FINISHED' and
      'my_widget' in (inbound, outbound);
```

If you want to count a row twice if the value occurs twice, then:

```
select sum(inbound = 'my_widget') + sum(outbound = 'my_widget')
from widgets
where event_name <> 'FINISHED' and
      'my_widget' in (inbound, outbound);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2515593209e57c996fa7d1255731c82a) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that no subquery is needed for this.